# Meteor window size not actual window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have Meteor running on Windows and encounter the following problem:

If I ask for `window.innerWidth` or `window.innerHeight` in the console I get a height of 905px. If I open another page, like Google, and ask for the window height in the console I get 995px, which is the true value my display resolution: 1080px minus 85px of bars. With the width it's similar: there are nearly 200 pixels missing.

I have created a new Meteor app using "meteor create test", started and logged the window height and width again, without (!) changing anything of the project (it's this click counter default application). Even in the new project this problem exists.

Why is that and how can I change this? Does it have something to do with the Windows version of Meteor?

Comment: Maybe you zoomed in for some reason your localhost:3000 tab and now it displays a different window size ?

Comment: It takes me some strength to admit that your totally right... Zoom out is not the solution to all problems in life but still to some of them ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The comment from saimeunt solved my problem.

If you encounter that check your browsers zoom for "localhost:3000".